# Sort Json Object in an array/text

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord.js, bots

I was wondering if i can sort the json keys in order as an array by the values.

Below is a json object

```json
{
  "p1": {
    "name": "*****",
    "age": "18"
  },
  "p2": {
    "name": "*****",
    "age": "14"
  },
  "p3": {
    "name": "*****",
    "age": "24"
  }
}
```

and i want it to get sorted in array/text in  ascending order by the values of the subkey "age".
`["p2", "p1", "p3"]`

I haven’t tried anything as I have no idea what to do, can someone return me an example…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Object.keys` and sort it based on their `age` properties:

```js
const data = { "p1": { "name": "*****", "age": "18" }, "p2": { "name": "*****", "age": "14" }, "p3": { "name": "*****", "age": "24" }}

const dataKeysSortedByAge = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => data[a].age - data[b].age)
console.log(dataKeysSortedByAge)
```

If the snippet is confusing:

1. `Object.keys` returns an array containing the keys in the object
2. The `sort` function takes a callback containing two parameters, where a positive value means `a` is greater, and a negative value means `b` is greater
3. We subtract one property's age from the other one; we can be lazy here and not convert the values to a number because substraction coerces the values to numbers

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the `<Object>#keys` method.

```js
const obj = {
    "p1": {
        "name": "*****",
        "age": "18"
    },
    "p2": {
        "name": "*****",
        "age": "14"
    },
    "p3": {
        "name": "*****",
        "age": "24"
    }
}
const keys = Object.keys(obj);

// Then sort
const sorted = keys.sort((a, b) => parseInt(obj[a].age) - parseInt(obj[b].age));
```

Comment: There's a lot going on here you might want to provide references for since the OP seems new. Specifically your use of [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#accessing_properties) to access dynamic properties and why you are using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (without a radix?). (subtraction actually obviates the need for explicit coercion as one is not at risk of accidental concatenation)